# Accessing table cells from a specific row to retrieve their embedded input value

Tags: javascript, html

I would like the function to return the result of this action on the values ​​from the table below:

> a+b*c-(e/f)

This action is worked whithout row with e and f. I found similar problem here but there is no solution for this one special last row. I'm shure how i should get value from e and f inputs. The function shul be workinf for each row - no matter how many of them will be.

```js
function calc(id) {
  var row = id.parentNode.parentNode;
  var a = row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var b = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var c = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var e = row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value; //not working
  var f = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value; //not working

  var res = +a + +b * c - (e / f);

  row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = res;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Calibri";
  margin: 0;
}

#inTotal {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.nr {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  background-color: #b9c1ce;
}

.Left {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th align="center" width="5%">A</th>
    <th align="center" width="10%">B</th>
    <th align="center" width="5%">C</th>
    <th align="center" width="15%">Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" width="5%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="quantity" min="1" max="99" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
    <td align="center" width="10%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="summ" min="0" max="999999" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
    <td align="center" width="5%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="rate" min="0" max="100" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
    <td align="center" width="15%"><input align="center" type="text" name="total" min="0" max="99999999"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" width="5%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="quantity" min="1" max="99" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
    <td align="center" width="10%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="summ" min="0" max="999999" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
    <td align="center" width="5%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="rate" min="0" max="100" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
    <td align="center" width="15%"><input align="center" type="text" name="total" min="0" max="99999999"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="center" width="5%">E</th>
    <td align="center" width="10%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="summ" min="0" max="999999" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
    <th align="center" width="5%">F</th>
    <td align="center" width="15%"><input align="center" type="text" name="total" min="0" max="99999999"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE
I wrote a function that was supposed to count the values ​​for data from lines with variables e and f. But unfortunately it lacks to be performed for all rows? I'm not shure how set numbers of rows to serve?

```js
function calc(element) {
  var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
  var a = row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var b = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var c = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

  // Getting the last row
//  var lastRow = document.getElementById("last-values");

  // Then, retrieving e and f
  //var e = lastRow.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  //var f = lastRow.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

  var res = +a + +b * c;

  row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = res;
}

function lastEle()
{ 
  var y = document.getElementById('e').value;
  var z = document.getElementById('f').value;
  
  var mytable = document.getElementById('myTable');
  var myinputs = mytable.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var rowy = mytable.rows.length;
  
  for (var i = 1; i < mytable.rows.length; i++) {
  
  var tmp = mytable.rows[i].myinputs[3].value;
  var wynik = +y + +z + +tmp;
  mytable.rows[i].myinputs[4].value = wynik;
}
}
```

```css
 body {
    font-family: "Calibri"; margin:0;}

#inTotal {
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.nr {
 font-weight: bold;
}
input {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
 text-align: center;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
 
}
th{
background-color: #b9c1ce;
}
.Left {
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr class="cipa"> 
<th align="center" width="5%">A</th>    
<th align="center" width="10%">B</th>
<th align="center" width="5%">C</th>
<th align="center" width="15%">D</th>
<th align="center" width="15%">F</th>
</tr>
<tr>                
<td align="center" width="5%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="quantity" min="1" max="99" onchange="calc(this);"></td>                    
<td align="center" width="10%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="summ" min="0" max="999999" onchange="calc(this);"></td>                        
<td align="center" width="5%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="rate" min="0" max="100" onchange="calc(this);"></td>                            
<td align="center" width="15%"><input align="center" type="text" onchange="calc(this);lastEle();" id="ads" name="total" min="0" max="99999999"></td>    
<td align="center" width="15%"><input align="center" type="text" onkeyup="lastEle();" value="3" name="total" min="0" max="99999999"></td>
</tr>
<tr>                
<td align="center" width="5%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="quantity" min="1" max="99" onchange="calc(this);"></td>                    
<td align="center" width="10%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="summ" min="0" max="999999" onchange="calc(this);"></td>                        
<td align="center" width="5%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="text" name="rate" min="0" max="100" onchange="calc(this);"></td>                            
<td align="center" width="15%"><input align="center" type="text" onchange="calc(this);lastEle();" name="total" min="0" max="99999999"></td>
<td align="center" width="15%"><input align="center" onkeyup="lastEle();" type="text" name="total" min="0" max="99999999"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <!--  e  -->
    <th>e</th>
    <td><input type="text" onkeyup="lastEle();" id="e"  value="" /></td>
    <!--  f  -->
    <th>f</th>
    <td><input type="text" id="f" onkeyup="lastEle();" value="" /></td>
  </tr>              
</table>
```

Comment: So when in which moment is problem. Sorry if is a stupid question but i'm trying learning js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Assuming `row` points to `<tr>`, you can access them this way, where `x` is the `(n+1)th` cell and `y` the `(n+1)th` input data :

```
row.cells[x].getElementsByTagName('input')[y];
```

Here, `y` could only equal `0`, because there is only one input element embedded in the `td` element.
To access the "e and f" row, simply set an id to their row:

```
<tr id="last-values">
    <!--  e  -->
    <th>e</th>
    <td><input type="text" value="5" /></td>
    <!--  f  -->
    <th>f</th>
    <td><input type="text" value="6" /></td>
  </tr>
```

Then, rewrite your calc() function:

```
function calc(element) {
  var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
  var a = row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var b = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var c = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

  // Getting the last row
  var lastRow = document.getElementById("last-values");

  // Then, retrieving e and f
  var e = lastRow.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var f = lastRow.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

  var res = +a + +b * c - (e / f);

  row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = res;
}
```

Keep in mind that you should write another function if e or f are updated: in this case, you'll have to loop the whole rowset to update the values. I let you write this part.

Below a working snippet (without the part of e and f updating).

```js
function calc(element) {
  var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
  var lastRow = document.getElementById("last-values");
  var a = row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var b = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var c = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var e = lastRow.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var f = lastRow.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;


  var res = +a + +b * c - (e / f);

  row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = res;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table th {
  background: #a0a0a0;
}

table td input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
    <th>c</th>
    <th>res</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--  a  -->
    <td><input type="text" onKeyUp="calc(this)" /></td>
    <!--  b  -->
    <td><input type="text" onKeyUp="calc(this)" /></td>
    <!--  c  -->
    <td><input type="text" onKeyUp="calc(this)" /></td>
    <!-- res -->
    <td><input type="text" onKeyUp="calc(this)" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="last-values">
    <!--  e  -->
    <th>e</th>
    <td><input type="text" value="5" /></td>
    <!--  f  -->
    <th>f</th>
    <td><input type="text" value="6" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think and understand your concept but do not you think it will look ugly? will it be a bad idea to get values from e and f in this way {var e = document.getElementById('e').value;}

Comment: I would like to retrive e from input next to field with E on gray back-ground and the same way f. E and F they are additional variables to which the above rows must refer in the table

Comment: wonderfull I am very grateful. Now I have to sit down and analyze and draw the appropriate conclusions ;).

Comment: You're welcome! I suggest you to start with [introduction to DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) and to keep an eye on the DOM [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). MDN Webdocs are very useful for Javascript/DOM programming. (Note: I remove my comments when a SO question is resolved, unless keeping them is relevant.) Happy coding. :)

Comment: I am asking you to take a look at the functions for e and f values ​​that I could change when filling the table? I update question

Comment: I conclude that I have solved my problem (I hope ;)!), and I am very grateful for your attention and advice. However If the problem, in the subject of this function would come back, I dare to ask you directly (if of course you will not mind :)) Regards

Comment: @simple_code I'm glad I could give you some help. Actually, it would be much better - and following SO principles to start a new question for each point and let the crows give you an answer. Regards (Note: you should save the links I gave you about DOM, I'm deleting unnecessary comments.)